# Parsing text using custom indicators

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, text

I am writing an iOS app in XCode that needs to parse a text file based on custom indicators that I have created. For example, < something> 12342asdf < something>, where < something> is the indicator. I was wondering if there are any good libraries out there to make the parsing easier. I have tried parsing using NSScaner, and even though it works, it will take a lot of time in order to write a complete parser.

Comment: If your file contains XML, can't you use NSXMLParser ?

Comment: Its not XML, the indicators are made by me

Comment: In that case using combination of NSScanner and NSString's string splitting methods

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time with NSScanner and it surely is slow. [This article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/01/c-code-outperforms-nsscanner/) helped, I'll summarize the conclusions from the article:
- Good C-code easily outperforms NSScanner
- Defer creating objects to the latest possible moment
- Avoid lazy instantiations if they are called in tight loops that cause them to be called too often
- Try to find simple mathematical or logical abort conditions (quickly processed) to avoid CPU-intense work where possible

Answer (score 0):

I've used `NSRegularExpression` to do this in the past to good effect. I've never done performance measurements, since it was operating on pretty small bits of text, but I've found that once you've compiled the expression (i.e. initialized the `NSRegularExpression` with a pattern) it was pretty fast.